# Ruby object to JSON and back

Tags: ruby, json, serialization, deserialization

I want convert a Ruby object into JSON and also convert back the JSON into Ruby object. With all codes that I have seen, the JSON is converted back into Hash (and not the custom Ruby object). Can somebody tell me how this can be achieved?

Comment: Give more information on what you are looking for. What custom class you are using? How json is being created? How your json looks like? etc..

Comment: AFAICS, you are interested in converting JSON into you own objects. Why not use the default constructor of _your_ object to get a hash as a param?

Comment: Any intermediate system that handled such JSON would at least need to respect the format (by preserving it), and may need to model fully (if it needed e.g. to generate a new object for later storage). That's easy of course if the JSON is only being emitted and consumed by the the self-same Ruby code - but if so, why not use existing persistence schemes such as Marshal or ActiveRecord? (In fact I wouldn't be surprised to find an ActiveRecord implementation that wrapped JSON serialisation for storage).

Comment: In fact, if you are using Rails, and/or ActiveRecord, see this: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from an object to JSON is lossy. In fact, the serialization process doesn't preserve the class.

The only way to restore it is to pass the class name as attribute in the serialized JSON and instruct the deserialization routine to instantiate an instance of that class.

Otherwise, if you know in advance the class, you simply add the ability to the class to initialize a new object from Hash.

Another alternative is to use YAML where the serialized output also stores the name of the original class.